# Median of specific transactions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have the following sheet:

[image]

I would like to take the median for all rows with a `K`.

I know how to take the median of all transactions. The hard part for me is "search for `K` and take only this transactions".

Any recommendations how to solve this?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(A2:A16="K",B2:B16))
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it

Comment: Thx for your answer! However I am getting `0` for the median, which cannot be possible... btw I used this: `=MEDIAN(IF(A2:A16="K";B2:B16))`

Comment: have you pressed CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to evaluate it, or just ENTER?

Comment: yep have pressed it several times! Any recommendation how to evaluate it differently?